Is Kurento Media Server supported on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS? How to install it?
I am looking to install Kurento Media Server on my system running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. I have searched through the official documentation and forums but haven't found any specific guidance for this version of Ubuntu.
Could someone please clarify the following:
1)Is Kurento Media Server officially supported on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?
2)If it is supported, what are the steps to install it? Are there any specific dependencies or configurations I should be aware of?
3)If it's not supported, are there any alternative solutions or versions of Kurento that I could use on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?
4) if not what version's of ubuntu is support kurento media server

You didn't search very far, since just searching for Ubuntu in their Installation guide I get: "Officially supported platforms: Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal) (64-bits)". And I think you're better off looking for something else, https://github.com/Kurento/kurento says: "This project is on bare minimum maintenance mode."

To install Kurento Media Server in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu  open the terminal and type:
sudo snap install kurento-media-server

This snap package is basically almost the latest version because the Kurento Media Server project is on bare minimum maintenance mode. There are no major new features planned for Kurento, and even minor issues may take some time to be addressed.
If you start looking for an alternative app, you'll find some alternative apps that are maintained actively, however these alternative apps may suffer from compatibility issues if you try to install them in Ubuntu.

Last updated in June 2017 according to https://snapcraft.io/kurento-media-server

But this is for ubuntu  16.04 LTS(which is End of Standard Support) i am asking latest version

This snap package is almost the latest version of  Kurento Media Server. See my edited answer for further details.
